# Why is my D3 stacked area chart flipped?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 chart that is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

This is the code i'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<svg id="chart"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var NSW = "NSW";
var QLD = "QLD";

var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var years = [];

var getStat = function(year, volatility, basis) {
    return {
        d: year,
        x: basis,
        vol: volatility,
        value: 45 * Math.pow(basis, year),
        high: 45 * Math.pow(basis+volatility, year),
        low: 45 * Math.pow(basis-volatility, year),
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    years.push(i);
}

var data = years.map(function(year){ return [getStat(year, 0.03, 1.08),getStat(year, 0.02, 1.08), getStat(year, 0.01, 1.08)]; });   // generate bogus data
var set_one = data.map(function(d) { return d[0];});
var set_two = data.map(function(d) { return d[1];});
var set_three = data.map(function(d) { return d[2];});

var chart = d3.select("#chart").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g");
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, years.length]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0].high, d[1].high); })]).range([0, height]);
var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
.y0(function(d, i){ return d.low}) //FUNCTION FOR BASE-Y
.y1(function(d, i){ return d.high * 0.99;}); //FUNCTION FOR TOP-Y

chart
.selectAll("path.area")
.data([set_one,set_two,set_three])          // !!! here i can pass both arrays in.
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")
.attr("class", function(d,i) { return [NSW,QLD,"T"][i]; })
.attr("d", area);

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your doing nothing wrong the y-axis goes downwards starting at `0` from the top down to `height`. So to flip it you can set the `y` values to `height - yValue`:

```
var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
.y0(function(d, i){ return (height - (d.low))}) //FUNCTION FOR BASE-Y
.y1(function(d, i){ return (height - (d.high * 0.99))}); //FUNCTION FOR TOP-Y
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yqm2jhx7/)

Answer (score 1):

the `y` ordinate in SVG increases downwards.  Try this...

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0].high, d[1].high); }), 0]).range([0, height]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everything in HTML / CSS / Canvas, the Y axis starts with `0` at the top and goes down to `height` at the bottom.

So according to your setup, the graph behaves correctly.

There are multiple ways to change the graphs direction.

a) You can change the range of your axis `var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([...]).range([height, 0]);`

b) You can change the domain of your axis `var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0].high, d[1].high); }), 0]).range([...]);`

or c) change the way the graph gets its y-values with `d3.svg.area().y0(...)` and `d3.svg.area().y1(...)`

I would recommend the first option, because this actually specifies the **range** your domain gets projected on.

Answer (score 1):

I think there was an issue with your y-scaling.I have inverted the range  from range([height, 0] which was initially range([0,height]) as this should be the way as per d3 norms otherwise you have to change the logic while calculating the height of plot.

Here I am attaching the fixed code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<svg id="chart"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var NSW = "NSW";
var QLD = "QLD";

var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var years = [];

var getStat = function(year, volatility, basis) {
    return {
        d: year,
        x: basis,
        vol: volatility,
        value: 45 * Math.pow(basis, year),
        high: 45 * Math.pow(basis+volatility, year),
        low: 45 * Math.pow(basis-volatility, year),
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    years.push(i);
}

var data = years.map(function(year){ return [getStat(year, 0.03, 1.08),getStat(year, 0.02, 1.08), getStat(year, 0.01, 1.08)]; });   // generate bogus data
var set_one = data.map(function(d) { return d[0];});
var set_two = data.map(function(d) { return d[1];});
var set_three = data.map(function(d) { return d[2];});

var chart = d3.select("#chart").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g");
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, years.length]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return Math.max(d[0].high, d[1].high); })]).range([height, 0]);
var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
.y0(function(d, i){ return y(d.low)}) //FUNCTION FOR BASE-Y
.y1(function(d, i){ return y(d.high * 0.99);}); //FUNCTION FOR TOP-Y

chart
.selectAll("path.area")
.data([set_one,set_two,set_three])          // !!! here i can pass both arrays in.
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")
.attr("class", function(d,i) { return [NSW,QLD,"T"][i]; })
.attr("d", area);

</script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you changed and what caused the problem.